# Rails: How to set up db:schema:load for initial deploy with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano3

I'm trying to deploy my `Rails 4` app using `Capistrano 3`. I'm getting error messages in running the `db:migrations` (i've been sloppy, sorry). Is there a way to have Capistrano deploy the app (at least the first time) using `db:schema:load`?

An excerpt of my `deploy.rb`:

```
namespace :deploy do

  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc 'Manage Unicorn'
    task command do
      on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 1 do
        execute "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{fetch(:application)} #{command}"
      end      
    end
  end
```

I'm not sure how to override `Capistrano 3`'s default behaviour. Can someone tell me how to add this to my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first time deploys, I generally hack around it by logging into the server, `cd`ing into the release directory (which will have the deployed code at this point), and then manually running `RAILS_ENV=yourenv bundle exec rake db:setup`.

Comment: Except it's a terrible workaround. We should never need to directly SSH to the server - if we're ok with running commands on the server, what's the point of Capistrano then?

Comment: Automation. The purpose of Capistrano is to allow you to not have to run the same long set of commands over and over.

Answer (score 1):

In Capistrano 3.10.1 with a Rails 5.1.6 application,

```
~/Documents/p.rails/perla-uy[staging]$ bundle exec cap staging deploy:updating
```

gives me enough to shell-in and run the `db:structure:load` or `db:schema:load` task manually. In the secure shell session to the host, switch to the newly created release directory and:

```
dclo@localhost:~/perla-uy/releases/20180412133715$ bundle install --without development test --deployment
dclo@localhost:~/perla-uy/releases/20180412133715$ bundle exec rails db:schema:load
```

Shelling into a (successful or failed) deploy that has tried `deploy:migrate` isn't quite the same.

Note: I have `RAILS_ENV=production` and `RAILS_MASTER_KEY=...` set-up by the shell login.